# How can I add operator ternary on section blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I try like this :

```
@section('title', 'Search' . '"' . empty($search) ? '' : $search . '" | Myshop')
```

On my view blade laravel

But it does not work

I want if `$search` exist, the result like this :

> Search "test" | Myshop

For example `$search` = test

IF `$search` not exist, the result like this :

> Search "" | Myshop

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean but "it does not work"? You get an error? What do you get? Please, define your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to display the results that you want you can use this:

If condition appoarch

`@section('title')
     Search  "@if(isset($search)){{$search}}@endif" | Myshop
 @endsection`

or

Ternary approach

`@section('title')
     Search  "{{isset($search) ? $search : ''}}" | Myshop
 @endsection`

instead your existing code.

Comment: It does not work. You try to read my question well. My code in `@section('title'...`

Comment: It works. But the message like this : `Search " test " | Myshop`. But there is a space between the double quote and the word

Comment: Answer updated. i removed the space before `{{` and after `}}`. Please check again and dont forget to marked answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `$search` will always be defined... this should work. If it's not defined, then use `isset` instead of `empty`.

```
@section('title', "Search \"" . empty($search) ? null : $search . "\" | Myshop")
```

Comment: I try your code, there exist error : `Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$startSection`. Should you try it first